# Django : OneToOneField - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

I have this two following classes in my model:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}, view: {1}".format(self.answer, self.answer_number)


class Vote(models.Model):
    answer = models.OneToOneField(Answer, related_name="votes", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer.answer)[:30]
```

In the shell I take the first Answer:

```
>>> Answer.objects.all()[0]
<Answer: choix 1 , view: 0>
```

I want to get the Vote object:

```
>>> Answer.objects.all()[0].votes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Hippolyte\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 420, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
questions.models.Answer.votes.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Answer has no votes.
```

But an error occured.

I don't understand why the `related_name` is not recognized. Could you help me ?

Comment: You used a `OneToOneField` here? That thus means that each `Vote` points to a *different* answer? Then there is thus at most one `Vote` per `Answer`, hence `some_answer.votes` will imedately query for a `Vote` object, and if it does not exists, it will raise a `DoesNotExists` error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `related_name` IS recognized, but it is only assigned to the instance if the related object exists.

In your case, there is no `Vote` instance in your database where its `answer` field points to your `Answer` instance

Just catch the exception and return `None` if you want to proceed:

```
answer = Answer.objects.all().first()
try:
   vote = answer.votes
except Answer._meta.model.related_field.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist as e:
   vote = None
```

If you want to shorten this you can use `hasattr(answer, 'vote')`, to check, but this will mask ALL exceptions arising from the db lookup if any

```
answer = Answer.objects.all().first()
vote = answer.votes if hasattr(answer, 'votes') else None
```

Note that since you used a OneToOneField, `answer.votes` will always return a single instance if the related `Vote` exists. As such, it would be more appropriate to use `related_name='vote'` (without the s)

Comment: `getattr(answer, "votes", None)` should be fine, no?

Answer (score 1):

You used a `OneToOneField` here. This thus means that each `Vote` points to a *different* `Anwer` object. There is thus *at most* one `Vote` per `Answer`. A query like `some_answer.votes` will immedately query for that `Vote` object, and if it does not exists, it will raise a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error (which is a subclass of a `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception). So the `related_name` itself is recognized, but there is no related `Vote` object.

It is however suprising to use a `OneToOneField` here. It means that each vote points to a unique `Answer`? I think you probably want to use a `ForeignKey` here, since otherwise a `related_name='votes'` makes not much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `Answer` has a `Vote` by querying the `Vote` model without using the OneToOne relationship

Try doing:

```
ans = Answer.objects.all()[0]
Vote.objects.filter(answer_id = ans.id).all()
```

Extra tip, you should use a singular word on related_name (`vote` instead of `votes`), because it is a OneToOne, meaning an Answer can only can one Vote (and vice-versa)